how to replace a service with a Subject with signals?
Say I have a very simple shared service holding a subject:
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
  private _runTaskSubject = new Subject<string>();
  
   get runTaskSubject$() {
     return this._runTaskSubject.asObservable();
   }

   runTask(name: string) {
     this._runTaskSubject.next(string);
   }
}

Observers of that runTaskSubject$ will only get notified once runTask is called.
Now I was thinking to convert this service using signals, but it seems that not an option as signals always hold an initial value. So does it makes sense to keep my rxjs Subject for this use case?

The signals equivalent for the same is as below.
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
  private _runTaskSignal = signal<string | undefined>(undefined);
  
   get runTaskSignal() {
     return this._runTaskSignal.asReadonly();
   }

   runTask(name: string) {
     this._runTaskSignal.set(name);
   }
}


We can set the initial value of the signal to be undefined to mimic the subject.

We can use asReadonly method to convert the signal to a readOnly signal, the advantage being the readOnly signal does not have access to set and update methods, hence if the signal should be updated, it can be updated only through the runTask method.

When you read the signal and do not want it to fire on initial load, all you need to do is check that the value is not undefined and then emit values.
  export class SomeComponent {
    myService: MyService = inject(MyService);

    constructor() {
      effect(() => {
        // simulate event bus
        const runTaskValue = this.myService.runTaskSignal();
        if(typeof runTaskValue !== 'undefined') {
          // ... some actions happen here!
        }
      });
    }
    ...



Full Code:
import { Component, Injectable, signal, inject, effect } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService {
  private _runTaskSignal = signal<string | undefined>(undefined);

  get runTaskSignal() {
    return this._runTaskSignal.asReadonly();
  }

  runTask(name: string) {
    this._runTaskSignal.set(name);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ myService.runTaskSignal() }}!</h1>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myService: MyService = inject(MyService);

  constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      // simulate event bus
      const runTaskValue = this.myService.runTaskSignal();
      if (typeof runTaskValue !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('value changed: ', runTaskValue);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.myService.runTask(`${Math.random()}`);
    }, 2000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I don't think an effect checking for undefined value is the way to go. What if my Subject in the service is a Subject<void>, how will you avoid checking the first emission in the effect in  that case?

@dalox Signals is not advertised as a replacement for rxjs or Subject, if you want to achieve it, why not go for a Subject instead, anyway this is the workaround to achieve what you want. There is no such thing as a void signal for now, because if you are going to do that, people will recommend you to use a subject instead

I understand, i guess I'd just stick to rxjs then. Thanks for your time.
